# group by unique column values in list using Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, group-by, pivot-table

I have a list with column namely A,B,C,D and I wanted to reformat list by a group of Unique D column's values. 
List

[image: List Picture]

Expected Output:

```
list=[d1[[1,11,n1],[1,22,n2]],d2[[3,33,n3]]
```

and then print all list under d1:

```
[1,11,n1],[1,22,n2]
```

Comment: Is it just me or is that image you linked to blank?

Comment: @ktdrv You are right, it's not your fault, this is the just first time I am trying to upload the image and not getting uploaded rightly, apologize, I am new to this place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*operator.itemgetter()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to extract the field of interest (field *3* is the *D* column).  Then use [*itertools.groupby()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to extract groups with a common key:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> data = [ [1, 11,'n1','d1'],
         [2, 22, 'n2', 'd1'],
         [3, 33, 'n3', 'd2'],
]
>>> data.sort(key=itemgetter(3))   # sort by column d
>>> result = []
>>> for k, groups in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(3)):
        entry = [group[:-1] for group in groups]
        result.append((k, entry))

>>> result
[('d1', [[1, 11, 'n1'], [2, 22, 'n2']]), ('d2', [[3, 33, 'n3']])]
```

If you just want to print the `d1` groups, the code is even simpler:

```
>>> for k, groups in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(3)):
        if k == 'd1':
            print([group[:-1] for group in groups])

[[1, 11, 'n1'], [2, 22, 'n2']]
```

The code `[group[:-1] for group in groups]` uses [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-slice) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) to remove the key-field as shown in your expected output.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: the list is having d1 values, where as I wasn't expecting that as a part of the output.

Comment: @AMOLKHADE I updated the answer to reflect that as well.  However, on StackOverflow you are expected to do at least some of the work yourself rather than asking someone to write the whole program for you.

Comment: Thank for the update, may I know how you are going to access it back to get the end part of the query? then print all list under `d1 i:e [1,11,n1],[1,22,n2]`